# iOS Crash Stack Deciphering

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

We receive multiple unreproducible crash reports from the field for our iPad app "MyApp" with about 3000 daily users. Reason: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"
Affected devices: only iPad 1.

The crash report refers to `[__NSCFDictionary buttonPressed:]` while `buttonPressed:` is the action of a UIButton. Apparently in the crash cases the button is not ready to receive the message yet. Instead the message is dispatched to some other instance in memory (which is in most cases a dictionary).

The action `buttonPressed:` is attached to the button via a xib file (with one additional case where the action is attached programmatically to an image view). `buttonPressed:` is the action the user might likely trigger at first when the app is brought to front. I suspect that in these cases the app is not fully initialized (brought back to front) and is unable to resume.

My suspicion is based on the symbols (always occurring in conjunction with these crashes): `_resourceLoadLoop` (performed in main thread?) and `_dispatch_mgr_wakeup`.

What is your opinion? Did you experience something similar with iPad 1 customers? Is there a known bug?

Here are the guts of a typical crash stack:

```
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-12-04 06:35:48 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x35a2f32c
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception \'NSInvalidArgumentException\', reason: \'-[__NSCFDictionary buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x40eaa0\'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x359b988f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x335dd259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                      0x359bca9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 175
3   CoreFoundation                      0x359bb915 ___forwarding___ + 301
4   CoreFoundation                      0x35916650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5   CoreFoundation                      0x359133fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 53
6   UIKit                               0x330d4e07 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 63
7   UIKit                               0x330d4dc3 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 31
8   UIKit                               0x330d4da1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 45
9   UIKit                               0x330d4b11 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 493
10  UIKit                               0x330d5449 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 477
11  UIKit                               0x330d392b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 319
12  UIKit                               0x330d3319 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 381
13  UIKit                               0x330b9695 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 357
14  UIKit                               0x330b8f3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5827
15  GraphicsServices                    0x336ab22b PurpleEventCallback + 883
16  CoreFoundation                      0x3598d523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 39
17  CoreFoundation                      0x3598d4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141
18  CoreFoundation                      0x3598c313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
19  CoreFoundation                      0x3590f4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
20  CoreFoundation                      0x3590f36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
21  GraphicsServices                    0x336aa439 GSEventRunModal + 137
22  UIKit                               0x330e7cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
23  MyApp                               0x0002411b main (main.m:14)
24  MyApp                               0x000240c0 start + 40


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35a2f32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x34c1029f abort + 95
2   MyApp                               0x0012d595 +[PLCrashReporter sharedReporter] + 1
3   CoreFoundation                      0x359b9957 __handleUncaughtException + 75
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x335dd345 _objc_terminate + 129
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x352253c5 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 77
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x35225451 operator delete(void*) + 1
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x35226825 __cxa_current_exception_type + 1
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x335dd2a9 objc_exception_rethrow + 13
9   CoreFoundation                      0x3590f50d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 405
10  CoreFoundation                      0x3590f36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
11  GraphicsServices                    0x336aa439 GSEventRunModal + 137
12  UIKit                               0x330e7cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
13  MyApp                               0x0002411b main (main.m:14)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35a1f3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x33d52bc9 _dispatch_mgr_wakeup + 1

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35a1f004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x3598d3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 127
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3598c12b __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3590f4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3590f36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   WebCore                             0x37655ca3 RunWebThread(void*) + 403
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x34bd8735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35a1f004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x3598d3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 127
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3598c12b __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3590f4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3590f36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                          0x34d54bb9 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 309
6   Foundation                          0x34d54a81 -[NSThread main] + 73
7   Foundation                          0x34de8591 __NSThread__main__ + 1049
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x34bd8735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35a2f570 __select + 20
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x34bd8735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35a2fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35a2fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000     r1: 0x00000000     r2: 0x00000001     r3: 0x00000000 
    r4: 0x00000006     r5: 0x3f2dbd98     r6: 0x00000002     r7: 0x2fe20a38 
    r8: 0x00469e00     r9: 0x00000000    r10: 0x00000000    r11: 0x0040eaa0 
    ip: 0x00000148     sp: 0x2fe20a2c     lr: 0x34c1720f     pc: 0x35a2f32c 
  cpsr: 0x00080010 

Binary Images:
   0x22000 -   0x288fff +MyApp armv7  <1f677ffc81aa3ccf958c65a92cce8418> /var/mobile/Applications/1D49C89A-36EA-43FC-BE76-7B770E36491B/MyApp.app/MyApp
0x3049d000 - 0x30550fff  iTunesStore armv7  <b3c0cce5f8e632e18f841c32b68f57a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x30555000 - 0x305d8fff  MapKit armv7  <e39706ac199134a497954e1f1d6d7245> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x305d9000 - 0x305dffff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x306dd000 - 0x306f1fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x30745000 - 0x30824fff  RawCamera armv7  <293f818ba6533dceae8b900b6ed3c887> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x30825000 - 0x30882fff  StoreServices armv7  <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x30883000 - 0x308cffff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x308f1000 - 0x30929fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x3092a000 - 0x30956fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x30ef1000 - 0x30f42fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30f43000 - 0x30f47fff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x30fb3000 - 0x30fb3fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x30fb4000 - 0x30fcafff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30fcb000 - 0x30fe0fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3129d000 - 0x312bafff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x312c0000 - 0x31433fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <63cdf8f9c66d36e7a4e69e2f6cae854f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x315ea000 - 0x315eafff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> 
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than being activated too soon, it's likely that the controller that implements `buttonPressed:` has been released and its memory re-used for another object.  If it's limited to certain devices it may be due to memory warnings...and the view unloading that has been removed from iOS 6.

Comment: This was my thought. Memory is dear on iPad1 and your app may be getting viewDidUnload messages. Did you implement them? You can test this in the simulator.

Comment: Well, the crash apparently is triggered by a user action. Therefore the view with its UIButton must be visible at that moment. In case the view controller's view got unloaded meanwhile, it must have been round-tripped through the viewDidUnload / viewDidLoad cycle. With the loading of the view via xib machinery the UIButton and its action must have been restored to working order.

Answer (score 0):

"unrecognized selector" exceptions where the message is being sent to a totally incorrect object are usually caused by double-release errors. This means your view controller (or whatever has the `buttonPressed:` method) has been deallocated, and its memory reclaimed by another object (in this case a dictionary).

You should check your memory management code. If you aren't already, I highly recommend to convert to ARC. This is backwards compatible to iOS 4 (if you don't use weak references) and will usually fix these kinds of problems for you.

To help debug this, you can enable zombie detection by editing your schemes diagnostic settings. You can also use the "zombies" instrument in Instruments. Both of these techniques can help confirm whether you have a double-release problem.

Comment: Even with zombie detection enabled we are not able to reproduce the crash on demand.